# Shift column based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift the column based on index.

In my example( I attached image), I just want to move index 4th to 5th column. Since 4th is named as null I could not iterate.

I have checked with following code,
if df.columns[4] != 'nan'
df.shift..

For me rows>5057 where columns got shifted.

Output: I just need to shift the column in index column 4 plus 1 and it will fine.

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
rows = df.iloc[:, 4].notna()
cols = slice(df.columns[4], None)

df.loc[rows, cols] = df.loc[rows, cols].shift(1, axis=1)
```

---

P.S.
If things go stranger, and there's no ways to organize your labels, then maybe it's better to use `numpy.array`:

```
data = df.values

index = ~np.isnan(data[:,4])
data[index, 5:] = data[index, 4:-1]
data[:, 4] = np.nan

df[:] = data
```

Comment: Thanks ..Good thought process, but Im getting error as 'Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: nan'. Any idea ??